# Как правильно экспортировать бэкграунд?

Tags: html, css

В общем у меня есть макет, в основной контентной части есть бэкграунд, который нужно вырезать картинкой по идее. Проблема в том, что этот бэкграунд идёт на всю высоту страницы (то есть и под шапкой он есть, и под футером).Как его правильно экспортировать и добавить в верстку?

Comment: Добавьте его к body ¯\(°_o)/¯

Comment: Макет в какой проге открываете? фш?

Answer (score 1):

Добавить в верстку можно с помощью css-свойства `background-image`, примененного к `body`. 
Правильно экспортировать можно так:

1. Если это нормальный файл со слоями, открыть его в соответствующем графическом редакторе и экспортировать только нужный слой (при необходимости - выполнить сведение нескольких слоев в один).
2. Если это файл со слоями, сделанный через одно место (например, тени или эффекты зависят от вышележащих слоев, не подлежащих экспорту), то либо манипулировать исходником, аккуратно удаляя лишнее, либо вернуть дизайнеру с просьбой прислать вариант, пригодный для верстки.
3. Если слой всего один, т.е., фон и элементы над ним - одно целое, то у вас два пути: а) если автор макета неизвестен, идти на поклон к кому-нибудь, кто восстановит фон, дорисовав его, и б) если автор известен, швырнуть ему файлом в морду со словами "вот теперь сам отделяй фон, редиска".